# SQL Server query : how can I SUM one SELECT to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with my SQL Server query, and I hope you will help me

The main select  must output date and sum of the weight

How can I sum one select to another? Data is taking from one table `Tbreport`, and condition is - to sum weight of the concrete date and previous date (concrete date minus 1 day)

For example:

```
CONCRETE DATE  WEIGHT 
  Jan 1         100                 
  Jan 2         150         
  Jan 3         210         

PREVIOUS DATE   WEIGHT 
  Jan 1          100 
  Jan 2          250 (Jan 1 + Jan 2)
  Jan 3          460 (Jan 1 + Jan 2 + Jan 3)
```

In real table I have format in seconds. For ex: 1358892000 seconds is 2013 Jan 23 0:00:00 and 1358978400 is 2013 Jan 23 23:59:00. And every time is own weight

Query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, TBreport.date, 25568), 102)  AS DATE,
    SUM(TBreport.weight) 
+ 
(
SELECT SUM(TBreport.weight) AS WEIGHT 
FROM         TBreport INNER JOIN TBway ON TBreport.id_way = TBway.id 
WHERE     (SUBSTRING(TBway.name, 5, 8) LIKE 'to warehouse')  
AND ... ???
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, TBreport.date, 25568), 102)  
)  
FROM         TBreport INNER JOIN TBway ON TBreport.id_way = TBway.id 
WHERE     (SUBSTRING(TBway.name, 5, 8) LIKE 'to warehouse')  
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, TBreport.date, 25568), 102)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `date` is unique in `TBreport`

```
SELECT this.date, SUM(upToThis.weight)
FROM TBreport this
INNER JOIN TBreport upToThis ON upToThis.date <= this.date
GROUP BY this.date
```

Comment: Why do you call this the 'ugly' way? And do you have another way to do it that would be less ugly?

Comment: Data is stored in seconds, and measures is taking every 5-10 minutes, after that weight sum up by the date. Your code is executing already 15 minutes (I think it doesn't work). 

And when I try to sum my queries I get this ERROR message
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
> subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: @Yohsoog It was "ugly" because it's probably very slow. Using a cursor would most likely be *much* faster.

Comment: @Jkterina So can you post the actual data you have? This query will work with the table you have posted.

Comment: In real table I have format in seconds. For ex: 1358892000 seconds is 2013 Jan 23 0:00:00 and 1358978400 is 2013 Jan 23 23:59:00. And every time is own weight